# IsChecked Binding not working in MenuItem in a ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I have an MVVM Application and want to add a ContextMenu.

I added the ContextMenu to XAML and then set the Items like this (only one item here because it doesn'T matter):

```
<MenuItem Header="{x:Static Monitor:MonitorResources.R0206_SaveLatestValueToDatabase}"
                                      IsCheckable="true"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Model.SaveToDbOneChecked}"
                                      IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Model.SaveToDbOneEnabled}">
```

The SaveToDbOneChecked and SaveToDbOneEnabled are Properties in my Model which are implemented like this:

```
    private bool mSaveToDbOneEnabled;

    public bool SaveToDbOneChecked
    {
        get { return mSaveToDbOneChecked; }
        set { mSaveToDbOneChecked = value; OnPropertyChanged("SaveToDbOneChecked"); }
    }
```

I set these before the ContextMenu gets called on the SelectionChanged in the GridView the ContextMenu is in. But it won't show the Checked sign next to the text of the MenuItem although the SaveToDbOneChecked has been set to true! I don'T know where i do something wrong and hope that somebody can help me here.

Comment: Run the application in debug and check for Binding Errors in output window.

Comment: Yeah there are quite a few :  Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=root'. BindingExpression:Path=Model.SaveToDbOneChecked; DataItem=null; target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'IsEnabled' (type 'Boolean')

what's my problem with the binding? o_O

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things you have to do to make this work. First of all you cannot bind from inside a `MenuItem` using `ElementName` property since the target element is most often out of your scope.

If I understand correctly the `Model` is your `ViewModel` property, in this case all you have to do is to set it as the `DataContext` of the Element on which the `ContextMenu` is placed.
This will set the same `DataContext` for your `MenuItem` and you can bind directly to  `DataContext`:

```
IsChecked="{Binding SaveToDbOneChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Comment: Awesome! That totally works! Thank you very much Sir!!